# How to return multiple fragments from FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, fragmentpageradapter

If I use a `TabLayout` with `FragmentPagerAdapter`, the overridden function getItem(int position) just return one fragment. In case of lager screen I would like to have 2 fragments to be returned.
How can I do it? should wrap these 2 fragments into one fragment and use that instead or is there any better solution?

**FragmentPagerAdapter:**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: //Ingredients
                return IngredientsFragment.newInstance(mRecipe);
            case 1: // Details
            {
                // TODO Here instead of DetailFragment I want to return
                // two fragments called DetailFragment and StepFragment.
                return DetailFragment.newInstance(mRecipe);
            }
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException(this.toString() + " Wrong fragment!");
        }
    }
```

**And then in my Activity onCreate:**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Initializing, etc.

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
    }
```

Comment: I think returning a fragment that wraps the two others is the sensible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I managed to solve the problem using a `Fragment` consist of two other fragments as children.
Just do not forget in this case the `FragmentManager` object should be populated with `getChildFragmentManager()` to work properly.
For more info look at my BakingApp project `DetailStepWideScreenFragment.java`

[GitHub Repos](https://github.com/wonderfulMe/BakingApp)

**Fragment Wrapper:**

```
public class DetailStepWideScreenFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_step_wide_screen, container, false);

        // I added the fragments here. StepFragment can be replaced using
        // replaceStepFragment function.
        DetailFragment detailFragment = DetailFragment.newInstance(mRecipe);
        StepFragment stepFragment = StepFragment.newInstance(mRecipe, mStepId);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fl_detail_fragment_wide_screen, detailFragment);
        transaction.add(R.id.fl_step_fragment_wide_screen, stepFragment);
        transaction.commit();

        return view;
    }

    public void replaceStepFragment(String stepId) {
        mStepId = stepId;
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        StepFragment stepFragment = StepFragment.newInstance(mRecipe, mStepId);
        transaction.replace(R.id.fl_step_fragment_wide_screen, stepFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**PagerAdapter:**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private DetailStepWideScreenFragment currentFragment;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        currentFragment = null;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: //Ingredients
                return IngredientsFragment.newInstance(mRecipe);
            case 1: // Details
            {
                // Show base on screen size.
                if (mIsLargeScreen) {
                    DetailStepWideScreenFragment detailStepWideScreenFragment = DetailStepWideScreenFragment.newInstance(mRecipe, "0");
                    currentFragment = detailStepWideScreenFragment;
                    return detailStepWideScreenFragment;
                } else {
                    return DetailFragment.newInstance(mRecipe);
                }
            }
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException(this.toString() + " Wrong fragment!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { return 2; }

    public DetailStepWideScreenFragment getCurrentFragment() {
        return currentFragment;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see you have much of a wiggle room here.

These two options are exlusive:

1. You are returning one Fragment with two nested fragments (Wrapped fragment)
2. You are returning two fragments each anchored to his own tab.

If you would like two fragments to appear on singular page of ViewPager, you have no choice but to wrap them. 
Otherwise swiping would go between these two fragments, which is the same as if they are completely different, that is non-correlated.